# Move cursor and make gf, but in previous file move to old position

Tags: vim

I know that plugin that can do it almost certainly exists. Or maybe I could use something like LSP for this. But I want to make my simple command, that will go to file with definition of component / function / class in JS. It's not difficult, because in JS all imports are explicitly, so I wrote this command in my .vimrc

`autocmd FileType javascript nnoremap gd gd/from<CR>:noh<CR>5lgf`

gd = go to definition (first occurrence of symbol)

/from = find from in this string (because string will be like "import smth from 'filename'")

:noh = remove unnecessary highlighting

5l = skip from word to move to filename

gf = go file

This works good, it goes to required file but when I return to my old file, my cursor is obviously on line with import, but I want to remain in line  for example(where I run gd command), but not in import ComponentName from './path/ComponentName'(for example). I heard about :keepjump but I don't understand how can I use it there. How can I do this ?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

### Assuming you didn't rename your import

With Vim default settings, eg `$ vim --clean main.js`, you should be able to use `gf` directly on any `ComponentName` in the buffer simply by setting the `:help 'path'` option properly.

In the example below, all I had to do was `:set path+=./x/y/z` (very explicit) but I could have simply done `:set path+=x/**` (more implicit):

[image: gf]

Of course, manually adding every single component directory is out of the question but front-end projects tend to have predictable structures so it won't be too difficult to write your own `set path+=components/**,src/**,<other directories>`.

### Assuming you renamed your import

Your mapping as is won't cut it because it is too brittle. Instead, we can take a different approach:

```
gd                                 " jump to local definition of current word
$                                  " move cursor to end of the line
F'                                 " move cursor to nearest single quote to the left
yi'                                " yank filename
<C-o>                              " jump back to usage
:execute 'find' getreg('"')<CR>    " find filename in path
```

which gives us this:

```
nnoremap <key> gd$F'yi'<C-o><Cmd>execute 'find' getreg('"')<CR>
```

--- EDIT ---

As per your comment, here is a quote-agnostic variant that uses a custom function to make the added complexity manageable:

```
function! FindModule()
    " jump to definition of current word
    normal! gD
    " move cursor to end of line
    normal!
    " move cursor to opening quote
    normal! gEW
    " move cursor inside the quotes
    normal! l
    " grab filename
    let fn = expand('<cfile>')
    " jump back back to usage
    " ^O is obtained by pressing <C-v> then <C-o>
    normal! ^O
    " find filename in path
    execute 'find' fn
endfunction
nnoremap <key> <Cmd>call FindModule()<CR>
```

--- ENDEDIT ---

---

You might find [this article](https://vimways.org/2018/death-by-a-thousand-files/) interesting.

Comment: Looks good. But is there way to yank filename, if it can be in 'so quotes' and "also in so quoutes" ?

Comment: Probably. Once you are at the end of the line, you could jump backward to the first space with `F `, move the cursor two chars to the right (so on the character immediately after `'` or `"`) and then do something with `:help c_ctrl-r_ctrl-f`.